# How secure is Google Sheets - Publish to web, when using for Power Bi report?

Tags: google-sheets, powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I am currently working on a Power BI report, which uses Google Sheets as the data source. As there are no official connectors available, there are two ways to fetch data from sheets to Power BI:
1. Publish to web
2. Link sharing

In both methods, we need to provide a link to Power BI which consists of the ID of the particular spreadsheet. In 'publish to web', any individual with the link can view my data.

So my main concern is, how secure the link sits in power BI? Are there any chances of breach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your concern should not be how the link is secured in Power BI Service, but the existence of this link itself. Lets say the probability of leaking  it from your IM/e-mail/correspondence is much higher than leaking from Power BI. You are sharing sensitive data for anonymous access. Don't do that! Find another way for reporting. Either use charting, etc. from Google Sheets, or if you need/must use Power BI, store the data in more convenient place. For example a database in the cloud (Azure SQL Database is a good one). Then build an ETL process to read your data from Google Sheets and push it to the database. This process will be fully authenticated and you will not expose your data.

Comment: Thanks a lot for sharing your views on this. In fact, I myself was thinking on the same lines. Can you please suggest the best ETL tool to get this done? I was thinking of Microsoft Flow to pull data from Google Sheets & then push in Azure SQL. Please guide further.

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't advise you which tool is "the best". This is quite subjective. I feel comfortable writing my own ETL for this, while others will prefer pre-made solution. Just use that one, which you feel comfortable with and you know best. If it works for you, it may be "the best" for you too :)

Comment: @AndreyNikolov, did you find a solution to this? I also have a similat requirement of securely storing the data in Azure SQL and using the ETL process.

Comment: @Gangula I know its too late. However, I just noticed your comment and wondering how google sheets publish to web is involved in your requirement since you are working with Azure SQL?

Comment: @PratikBhavsar, I actually am not yet working with Azure SQL but I'm planning to. So I was wondering how if it possible to do this.

Comment: @Gangula Azure Data Factory or simple SSIS could be your solution